# Strange Powershell "interactive" behavior

Tags: powershell, powershell-5.0

Sometimes, when using certain commands within Powershell, the console is set into some kind of "interactive mode", which makes it behave in a way that's completely unusable for me, so I have to restart the console. I'm not sure whether it's a bug in Powershell or a feature I do not know about.

Here's a way to reproduce it (however, this is by far not the only way it happens):

- Navigate your Powershell console to a Git repository which is not too new, i.e. has at least a few dozen commits.
- Enter `git reflog`.
- Git shows the list of the recent `HEAD` positions, which most of the time is a list of the last commits.
- Press <kbd>Ctrl+C</kbd> or <kbd>q</kbd> to quit the list and return to the console.
- Optionally, press `cls` to clear the console screen.

Now, the console is in this weird mode. When I start typing, the console accepts some of the typed characters as usual, but some key presses seemingly let the console display fragments of the previous `git reflog` command.

Here is an example: In a fresh powershell console, I did the steps described above. Then I entered `abcdefghijklmn`. This is what this console is looking now:

[image]

As you can see, the characters <kbd>j</kbd> and <kbd>l</kbd> were treated like some commands that printed parts of the `git reflog` output to the console window, but **below** the prompt.

Is that a bug or a feature? Anyone else having these problems?

Comment: actually this happen when your brackets is open . try close bracket maybe its fix or you use [Shift+enter]

Comment: @saftargholi Just tried that, does not work. Not with `)`, `]`, nor `}`.

Comment: i have really no idea about it sorry.

Comment: I can repro this if I use 'ctrl-c', but never if I use 'q' at the git ':' prompt.  Can't explain it, but if you get this this state, 'q' at the next ':' prompt you get does seem to exit completely.  Strange.

Comment: @KoryGill You're right, with `q` this state does not appear. I must have confused something. However, once I'm in this state, `q` does not seem to help.

Comment: I may have used up arrow to get the ':' again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Explanation

`less` (default Git pager) does not interpret <kbd>Ctrl+C</kbd> as a quit command. You can open a new console window where `less` will be the only application attached to it: `start git reflog` to verify that.

When you press <kbd>Ctrl+C</kbd> and `less` is not the only application attached to the current console window, then <kbd>Ctrl+C</kbd> gets received by the shell (PowerShell or CMD), and the shell asks the user for more input. You can see in task manager that after you press <kbd>Ctrl+C</kbd>, `less` is still running, although the shell prints a new prompt for you. So now you have two applications which compete for single console window input buffer: some keys will be received by the first application, while other keys by the second application.

## Solution

You need to type <kbd>q</kbd> and <kbd>Enter</kbd> multiple times to make sure `less` will receive its `q`.

Comment: Thank you. Do you know why Powershell does not quit `less` when I press Ctrl+C?

Comment: @cheeesus I think, it is supposed for application to quit itself, rather than being killed by shell. For example, CMD also does not kill `less` on Ctrl+C.

Comment: @cheeesus Also note, when you run multiple shells recursively and press Ctrl+C, it does not make all shells to show theirs prompts. So, last shell handles and cancel Ctrl+C request, but, apparently, `less` does not do the same and cause this confusion.